# UNC path error in C# when output the file

Tags: c#

The programme is developed with C# and the error occurs during the process of outputing.
When the software runs on the local PC,there is no error however when runs on the Service an error occurs :**UNC path should be \server\share**.

I guess the error happens on this sentence:

Directory.CreateDirectory(m_path);

Comment: what value does m_path has? does that directory exist on the server? I know you are trying to create a directory, but maybe one of the top directories doesn't exists

Comment: how the software can run over service? what is path? what is your input ?what is the detailed exception?

Comment: The m_path get form the openFileDialog() method.this programme is in Winform,which runs on the local PC successfully but can run on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert a local path to a UNC path. [Network Shares and UNC paths](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2939/Network-Shares-and-UNC-paths) Encapsulates information about a single network share, including the server name, share name, share type, local path and comment. Also has some utility methods to determine if it is a file-system share, whether it matches part of a local path, and returns the root directory.

You can also use WMI to get the info like

```
using (ManagementClass shares = new ManagementClass(@"\\NameOfTheRemoteComputer\root\cimv2", "Win32_Share", new ObjectGetOptions())) {
    foreach (ManagementObject share in shares.GetInstances()) {
        Console.WriteLine(share["Name"]);
    }
}
```

but Appropriate permissions are required.